# How to find out particular element present in the website using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

How to find out if the entire website code contains C10.
If we inspect this element, **id=“ot-header-id-C10”**, OneTrust side this particular category id is C10.

1. other websites may not contain the same highlighted id but probably ending with C10 all I need to consider C10 present in the website or not.
2. The below code works with finding out the `id=“ot-header-id-C10"`
3. How to find the `element`, `ids`, or anywhere on the website that contains `C10`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
capabilities["marionette"] = True

fp.set_preference("browser.cache.disk.enable", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.cache.memory.enable", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.cache.offline.enable", False)
fp.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False) 
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=capabilities, firefox_profile=fp)

url = "https://www.axe.com/nl"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
time_to_wait = 10
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, time_to_wait).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h4[@id='ot-header-id-C10']")))
    print('Element with C10 attribute found')
    print(element)
except:
    print("C10 element not present")
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a clear indication if there are any elements on the page containing "C10" in any of their attributes or not.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(.,'C10')]")
if(elements):
    print("Elements containing C10 found on the page")
```

`//*[contains(.,'C10')]` will match any element containing "C10" in any attribute.
`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(.,'C10')]")` will return a list of matching web elements. If there are such elements found - the list will be non-empty, non-empty list is interpreted as `True` in python.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

```
//*[contains(@id, 'C10') or contains(@class, 'C10')]
```

this basically tells you to select any tag i.e : `span`, `div`, `button`, etc.

and if they have `attribute` like `id` or `class` and basically if that attributes contains the `C10`.

**Note that** you can have multiple attribute in the above `xpath` with `or` separation.

Comment: C10 may present in data-optanongroupid=C10, 
name='ot-group-id-C10' and for='ot-group-id-C10 not only in class and id.

Comment: Write or and then name or then for etc.. this is the closest solution you can get. It's simply what you do it in any programming. You can read more about or operator in Java, python or any programming language